# How to calculate big numbers in java?

Tags: java

**ex**
I want the sum form 1^1 to n^n  : 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + .............+n^n
and I know how, but the problem that I want only the last ten numbers of the sum but I have only to use primitive data. how can I calculate large numbers **using only primitive data.**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    short n = in.nextShort();
    if(n < 0) {
        System.out.println("please give a positive number");
        return;
    }
    long l  = rechnung(n);
    System.out.println(l);
    String str = Objects.toString(l, null);
    String s = ziffer(str);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static long rechnung(short j) {
    long summe = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= j; i++) {
        summe += Math.pow(i,i);
    }
    return summe;
}

public static String ziffer(String s) {
    String str = "";
    int k =s.length() - 10;
    int cond = k + 9;
    if(s.length() <= 10) {
        return s;
    }
    for(int j = k; j <= cond; j++) {
        str = str + s.charAt(j);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicholasK I have only to use primitive data types

Comment: *Why* do you only have to use primitive data types? If it's because this is a school project, I would *guess* that the aim is for you to implement your own limited form of `BigInteger`.

Comment: When does the problem arrives ? With long type you can handle a big part no ? also you can cute to 10-length each time you compute the **pow** and just sum the 10 digit each time

Comment: with n^n = 16^16 the long data type run over the flow.when I sum.

Comment: ˋRechnungˋ and ˋZifferˋ – sounds like a German Engineering Problem – I like

Comment: @JonSkeet the goal is not to  implement `BigInteger`. the goal is to get the last 10 digit of a really really huge number using only primitive data

Comment: @AhmedRamadan: I suspect it's actually simpler to implement just the bits of `BigInteger` you need, compute the complete value and then take the last 10 digits, than to work out how all the maths works without ever needing more than 10 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only need to keep the lower 10 digits you can use a % 10_000_000_000L to keep the digits you need with each calculation.